# wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

So I've just made a custom post type for my wordpress theme named "Products". When I create a new post in it and view it, the link is something like this:

"http://localhost/wordpress/product/a-product-title"

This page views as expected but when I try to go to the supposed parent page:

"http://localhost/wordpress/product/"

I get a 404 error page. Is there a special template I need to make to view this page?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what to do. I just created a new page called "Products" and set it as the posts page. Then I put this in front of the loop

$wp_query = new WP_Query("post_type=product");

and it worked

Comment: But that will override the normal loop if the OP is also making use of the standard post type (i.e running a typical blog).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - I think it's down to the fact that right now, WP 3.0 simply does not behave as you would expect with custom post type 'archives'.

Check out [Smarter Custom Posts](http://somadesign.ca/2010/smarter-custom-post-types-in-wordpress-3-0/) to easily build-in this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The name Products is also used by Woocommerce so be aware that if you  install this too, the custom post type will stop working.